# How do I nest views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, razor

I currently have a DIV inside a view, which I .load() at runtime (via jQuery) with the create view for another controller.  this works but when I look at the page the div is empty (of course).  I'm doing this because I haven't figure out how to embed a view within a view.

what I need is some kind of inclusion statement.  I found @RenderPage() but that won't issue a controller method call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Html.Action will allow you to nest a view inside of the view making that call - typically you would only do that on methods that return partial views, but that will get the job done here.

See [Html.Action vs Html.RenderAction](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx)

Comment: If you need to use jQuery to load your partial view, just have jQuery call the action method on your controller which returns the  PartialViewResult; if you decorate that action method with [ChildActionsOnly] it may not work when you invoke it via AJAX, but I don't know that for certain.

Comment: loading the partial view with jQuery is what I was doing.  the problem is that you can't just view source and see what is inside the div because you'll just see an empty div... you have to look with the debugger instead.  your suggestion of Html.Action works great!

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the hardest things about MVC in my opinion.  You can use

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.something, "SomeDisplayTemplate")
```

but this only works for display-only views, not so much editable views.  For those, particularly in the (common) use case where the main model has a collection that you want to provide editors for, you need to implement something like what Jarret recommends here:

http://jarrettmeyer.com/post/2995732471/nested-collection-models-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Comment: that's a really cool article. I don't need it for what I'm doing but I will need it down the road.  thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I actually go to my controller using jQuery.Post and I return a PartialView.

I then take the returned HTML and use jQuery to place that html into the target div.

Controller code

```
public ActionResult jQuery_GetEditPositionView(string id)
{
    PositionsRepository repository = new PositionsRepository();
    contract model = repository.Single(x => x.id == new Guid(id));
    return PartialView("ContractPositionEdit", model);
}
```

jQuery / Javascript

```
    function editPosition(id) {
        $.post('/Member/jQuery_GetEditPositionView', { id: id }, function (newHTML) {
            $('#newPositionDialog').html(newHTML);
            $("#newPositionDialog").dialog("open");
            $(".frmNewContract").validate();
        });
    }
```

Comment: yip.  that's close to what I'm doing (I actually use a .load()) but, for the reasons stated, want to move away from that to an inclusion of sorts... the @Html.Action does that

Answer (score 0):

If you are just simply wishing to embed a 'view inside a view', you can accomplish this with the concept of partials, see [`Html.Partial()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407417.aspx).

For example in standard ASP.NET notation:
`<%= Html.Partial(string partialViewName) %>`

or with Razor syntax:
`@Html.Partial(string partialViewName)`

For example: `<%= Html.Partial("_myView") %>` (which would be `_myView.ascx` in your `Views\<action>` or `Shared` folder.

Good luck.

Comment: forgive me but it isn't clear to me how I would specify a given view, for example, I have /Views/Product/Create.cshtml and /Views/Vendor/Create.cshtml - I tried @Html.Partial("Vendor/Create.cshtml"), @Html.Partial("Vendor/Create"), @Html.Partial("/Vendor/Create") and @Html.Partial("Create", Website.Models.Vendor) (which complains I'm passing the wrong type)... how exactly is this supposed to work?

Comment: Probably `Html.Action()` is your best bet now as it will evaluate your action, and return the view's contents. This would just render the "view" portion which is setup as an .ascx. However I believe what you wanted was `@Html.Partial("~/Views/Vendor/_Create.cshtml")` if you were using Razor and your partial view was called `_Create.cshtml`.